# How do I get the first and the last digit of a number in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get the first and the last digit of a number? For example 2468, I want to get the number 28. I am able to get the ones in the middle (46) but I can't do the same for the first and last digit.

For the digits in the middle I can do it

```
$substrmid = substr ($sum,1,-1); //my $sum is 2468
echo $substrmid;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reading the [PHP Docs page for substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) always helps: `$first = substr($sum, 0, 1); $last = substr($sum, -1);`

Answer (score 17):

You can get first and last character from string as below:-

```
$sum = (string)2468; // type casting int to string
echo $sum[0]; // 2
echo $sum[strlen($sum)-1]; // 8
```

OR

```
$arr = str_split(2468); // convert string to an array
echo reset($arr); // 2 
echo end($arr);  // 8
```

Best way is to use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) described by [*Mark Baker*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) in his comment,

```
$sum = 2468; // No need of type casting
echo substr($sum, 0, 1); // 2
echo substr($sum, -1); // 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like this:

```
<?php

$a = 2468;
echo substr($a, 0, 1).substr($a,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this (without casting).

```
$num = 2468;
$lastDigit = abs($num % 10); // 8
```

However, this solution doesn't work for decimal numbers, but if you know that you'll be working with nothing else than integers, it'll work.

The `abs` bit is there to cover the case of negative integers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$num = (string)123;
$first = reset($num);
$last = end($num);
```

Comment: you can't call `end` on a string